# How can I make a function print the square of the input value? (DataStructure, AVL tree)

Tags: c, data-structures, avl-tree

**[what I want to implement]**
In AVL tree, I need to make a function:
If the input node is in the AVL tree, it will be deleted. However, when the input node isn't in the AVL tree, it has to square the input node and push it.

**[code description]**
There are several functions to implement this.
I've got the AVL tree's height using `getBF`function to get the balance factor and used it to `rebalance` when the tree becomes imbalanced. Then I made the `doubleInsert` function to square the input node and used this in `deleteNodeDoubleInsert` function: the function that I want to implement. It's mainly focused on deleting the node. 'doubleInsert' is used when the inserted node doesn't exist in the tree.

**[what I've tried]**
When I only used `doubleInsert` function by itself, it worked just fine. Also, when I've deleted `doubleInsert` from `deleteNodeDoubleInsert` and replace it with simple `return;`, it worked too. However, when I've used the `deleteNodeDoubleInsert` function with `doubleInsert` just like the code below, it didn't work and the code just ended. What could be the problem?

```
/*It squares the input node*/
treeNode *doubleInsert(treeNode **root, element x){
    element xx= x*x;//square
    if(*root== NULL){
        *root= (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        (*root)-> key= xx;
        (*root)-> left= NULL;
        (*root)-> right= NULL;
    }
    else if(xx< (*root)-> key){ 
        (*root)-> left= insert_AVL_Node(&((*root)-> left), xx);
    //treeNode *insert_AVL_Node(treeNode **root, element x)
    //: it inserts the nodes to the AVL tree
        *root= rebalance(root);
    //`rebalance`function does
    }
    else if(xx> (*root)-> key){
        (*root)-> right= insert_AVL_Node(&((*root)-> right), xx);
        *root= rebalance(root);
    }
    else {
        printf("\n이미 같은 키가 있습니다.\n");
    }
    return *root;
}
```

```
/* the function that I want to implement */
treeNode* deleteNodeDoubleInsert(treeNode *root, element key){
    treeNode *parent, *p, *succ, *succ_parent;
    treeNode *child;
    parent= NULL;
    p= root;

    while((p != NULL) && (p-> key != key)){
        parent= p;
        if(key< p-> key) p= p-> left;
        else p= p-> right;
    }

    //if there is no node existing
    if(p== NULL){
        doubleInsert(&root, key);
    }

    //when the node doesn't have any chlild
    if((p-> left== NULL) && (p-> right== NULL)){
        if(parent != NULL){
            if(parent-> left== p) parent-> left= NULL;
            else parent-> right= NULL;
        }
    }

    //when the node has 1 child
    else if((p-> left== NULL) || (p-> right== NULL)){
        if (p-> left != NULL) child= p-> left; 
        else child= p-> right;

        if(parent != NULL){
            if(parent-> left== p) parent-> left= child;
            else parent-> right= child;
        }
        //when the node is root
        else root= child;
    }

    //when the node has 2 children
    else {
        succ_parent= p;
        succ= p-> left; //p's left subTree
        while (succ-> right != NULL){
            succ_parent= succ; 
            succ= succ-> right;
        }
        //link succ_parent and succ child
        if(succ_parent-> left== succ)
            succ_parent-> left= succ-> left; 
        else succ_parent-> right= succ-> left;

        //data swap to free p
        p-> key= succ-> key; 
        p= succ;
    }
    free(p);
}
```

```
/*print AVL tree*/
void displayPreorder (treeNode *root) {
    if (root) {
        printf("%10d", root->key);
        displayPreorder(root->left);
        displayPreorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

```
int main(){
      deleteNodeDoubleInsert(root_AVL, userData);
      printf("AVL 트리: ");
      displayPreorder(root_AVL);//
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your code all the type and variable definitions are missing.

Comment: Aside: your `doubleInsert` seems overly complicated to me: you're returning the new root _and_ passing in a reference to `root`, which you then modify - one or the other should do.

Comment: code format and grammar